# Redirect to another webpage having basic authorization

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a url having Basic Authorization applied to it. I need to redirect to this url from another url and need to pass the credentials in the header. I can use jquery/javascipt/mvc or any other way to do so. 
I tried using window.open(), location.replace(), $.ajax() etc but I am not able to assign any headers in these.
Is there any way to redirect to url or open a url in separate window and pass the authorization header in the request?

Comment: But if you store the credentials in your JavaScript then they will be visible to anyone who visits your website (they can look at the source code of the site) which makes the authentication useless. So your whole premise for the question is a bit strange

Comment: @ADyson I am using basic authentication for service to service communication and the credentials will be stored on the server. I first tried using [Redirect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirect?view=aspnetcore-3.0) method in asp.net core mvc and but it doesn't allow adding any headers. Redirecting from the server would be the preferred way. I tried using javascript/jquery just to create a dummy flow.

Comment: "Redirecting from the server" doesn't make any sense. All the server can do is tell the browser where to go next. It does that by setting a Location response header containing a URL when it sends info back to the browser. It's up to the browser to make a new request to visit that URL. The server cannot control what headers the browser sets when it does so.

Comment: If this protected page is in the same domain as your MVC site then you might be able to set a suitable cookie in the browser to allow it to authenticate automatically. But if you're going to give the user the credentials in their browser and log them in automatically, then I don't really quite understand the point of making the page have authentication to begin with?

Comment: There is an open issue for adding support for headers to the window.open function in the HTML standard. Please voice your opinions and needs on there. [https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810)